# Installing purchased apps by terminal

Tags: software-center

I've been trying to reinstall all my purchased apps on a new machine, and I ran into a problem. Because of the size of them (about 10-12GB in total) and the fact that downloading them is painfully slow for whatever reason (at most 800kB/s), it takes a lot of time (not to mention USC crashing). And then, when I tried to leave them overnight, none of them were installed and everything was at the same spot I left it.

Is there anyway to install them via terminal? Like some kind of USC backend were I could just add the archives for apps listed as purchased and then install them via apt-get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't any way to install the purchased app via terminal yet. You must use the Ubuntu software center, because it must have to be passed through authentication and verification.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping there was some way to do those things via the command line, but I guess not yet (or possibly ever).