# Purchase apps through Terminal instead of GUI Software Center

Tags: package-management, software-installation, software-center

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/687836/367990) made me wonder whether it's also possible to purchase Ubuntu apps through the **terminal** instead of the GUI Software Center.

In [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/204979/367990) from 2012, the only answer states that it was not possible at that time.

Can it be done now? If yes, how?
I really expect a solution to be existing, as usually everything else can be done via command-line in Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot purchase apps via terminal rather than Software Center.

You can install apps which you've previously purchased, via terminal. You will just need to add the PPA with your authentication token, and know the package name, to be able to install the packages for previously purchased apps.

You can see your [list of subscriptions](https://software-center.ubuntu.com/subscriptions/), from where you can get all the PPA info. You'll need to manually add the PPAs to a new file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and import the GPG keys for each PPA using *gpg* and *apt-key*:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key XXXXXXXX
gpg --export XXXXXXXX | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then you can update and install the package for the app you bought:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install purchased-app
```

Comment: Are you *sure* there's no way to actually buy through the terminal? I've never done it, so I don't know what stuff is necessary, but there should be a way, even if it's no easy way. - I still appreciate your current answer though. :)

Comment: Yes I'm sure. :) It is theoretically possible to write a new client program to be able to do so, but there exists no such program currently, and there are no plans to write one.